# Post raw form data from web page

Tags: javascript, http, forms, post, dhtml

I would like to send raw post data using straightforward DHTML, but without using the XMLHttpRequest object. Is this possible to do this, for example, by forcing an HTML form element's post data to an arbitrary string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you post the form, you could dynamically add html input elements (with values) to the form, and then call form.sumbit().  This will still refresh the page though.

The only way that I'm aware of to post data without refreshing the page is using the XMLHttpRequest object.  Using jQuery makes this whole operation pretty trivial http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ , so I'm not sure why you don't want to use ajax to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't mind refreshing the page; the point is that I don't want to be bound to the name1=value1&name2=value2 format. I'm looking for a way be able to post data in an arbitrary format, and I'll use XMLHttpRequest (or a library such as jQuery) only as a last resort.

Comment: There's no way (that I'm aware of) to assign data to a form other than through html input elements. However it wouldn't be hard to create a simple utility function to do the dirty work so you can work exclusively with the arbitrary format in the rest of your code.

Comment: So, your answer is: if I want an arbitrary postdata format, I must use the XMLHttpRequest object to make it happen. To avoid cross-browser implementation headaches, I can use jQuery. That's good enough for me.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're still going to have to post at least one data field as key:value - that's the way the server will expect the data to arrive.  Of course you can still put all your semantics into a single long value.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily generate a string that resembles a POST request. There is not much difference between a POST and a GET. Using GET, the parameters are added behind the url. When POSTing, the parameters are added in the same way, but below the headers.

See [developers.sun.com](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/HTTPPost/) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for some pure HTML/Javascript that will do the trick. It is imperative that my arbitrary data be transmitted as raw POST data, not as a query string.